# Rails, Getting a File's name when uploading a file to the server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip

I'm using an AJAX uploader in Rails 3, along with paper_clip and have files uploading here:

```
  def upload

    @photo = Photo.create({ :photo => params[:file], :title =>  params[:filename]  })

    respond_to do |format|
      format.json
    end
  end
```

I want to set the photo's title as the photo's filename, but don't know how to, even though params[:file] does have the file and is being uploaded to S3.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: @user479959 Don't know offhand. Either dig through paperclip documentation or `raise params.inspect` and see if the filename is anywhere in there.

Answer (score 34):

`params[:file].original_filename` has the filename you are looking for.

Comment: works even with Rails 1.2.6. (I'm working on a legacy codebase)

Answer (score 0):

params[:name] should have the name of the attachment and params[:mime_type] which shows the mime type will be available in the params which u can use. Just to verify, you can use raise params.inspect like how Jamie Wong suggested.