# How to capture name of file uploaded and display it in RoR application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to create a ROR application that allows me to upload excel files. I want to be able to list out the names of all excel files uploaded with a clickable link to each name that will bring me to the show.html.erb page which will show the data of the file.

I can't capture the name of file (report) uploaded and equate it to title_name so that it can be listed out in index.html.erb page.

Here is my schema:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20170402043056) do

  create_table "files", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "Name"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  create_table "reports", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "date"
    t.string "order"
    t.string "item"
    t.string "product"
  end

end
```

I have added this to routes.rb:

```
resources :reports do
  collection { post :import }
end
```

Reports model:

```
class Report< ActiveRecord::Base

require 'roo'
belongs_to  :file

def self.import(file)
  spreadsheet = open_spreadsheet(file)
  header = spreadsheet.row(1)
  (2..spreadsheet.last_row).each do |i|
    row = Hash[[header, spreadsheet.row(i)].transpose]
    report = find_by_id(row["id"]) || new
    report.attributes = row.to_hash
    report.save!
  end
end

def self.open_spreadsheet(file)
  case File.extname(file.original_filename)
  when ".csv" then Roo::CSV.new(file.path, packed: false, file_warning: :ignore)
  when ".xls" then Roo::Excel.new(file.path, packed: false, file_warning: :ignore)
  when ".xlsx" then Roo::Excelx.new(file.path, packed: false, file_warning: :ignore)
  else raise "Unknown file type: #{file.original_filename}"
  end
end

end
```

reports_controller:

```
class ReportsController < ApplicationController

def index
@file = File.all
end

def show
@file = File.find(params[:id])
end

def import
@report = Report.import(params[:file])
@file = File.import(params[:id])
redirect_to reports_path, notice: "report imported."
end

end
```

new.html.erb (page to upload file):

```
<%= form_tag import_reports_path, multipart: true do %>
  <%= file_field_tag :file %>
  <%= submit_tag "Import" %>
<% end %>
```

index.html.erb (page to list out names of files uploaded):

```
<h1>List of reports uploaded</h1>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Created at</th>
      <th>Updated at</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <% @report.each do |report| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= report.original_filename %></td>
        <td><%= report.created_at %></td>
        <td><%= report.update_at %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

show.html.erb (page showing the data):

```
<h1>Report data</h1>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Date</th>
      <th>Order</th>
      <th>Item</th>
      <th>Product</th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <% @report.each do |report| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= report.date %></td>
        <td><%= report.order %></td>
        <td><%= report.item %></td>
        <td><%= report.product %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: You should better use uploading gems such as paperclip or carrierwave, they both serves original filenames

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rails, Getting a File's name when uploading a file to the server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4002448/rails-getting-a-files-name-when-uploading-a-file-to-the-server)